# Searching docker hub registry images/layers by their SHA digest

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

If you ever attentively browse for docker images on https://hub.docker.com you may have once dissect all the [commands](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) composing an image of interest within a certain [tag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/).

Great, but then you may have seen this kind of "translated" command when you click on a specific  line of a command:

[image: A Docker file FROM... somewhere]

I may be wrong here because I'm not a Docker expert, but this seems to be an [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) digest which refers to... something else inside the Hub.

My question is; how to find ***what*** exactly does it refer to, knowing the SHA value (`3a7bff4e139bcacc5831fd70a035c130a91b5da001dd91c08b2acd635c7064e8`)?

Comment: Do you have an example of a image with that layer?

Answer (score 3):

The SHA value you see is the digest of the file that was added.

For example, suppose you have the following dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
ADD foo.txt /foo.txt
```

If you were to push that to dockerhub, you would see something like:

```
ADD file:b5bb9d8014a0f9b1d61e21e796d78dccdf1352f23cd32812f4850b878ae4944c in /
```

where `b5bb9d8014a0f9b1d61e21e796d78dccdf1352f23cd32812f4850b878ae4944c` is the digest of `foo.txt`.

There's no definitive way to reverse this information to obtain the file, considering `ADD` can do things like unpack tar archives.

With modern versions of Docker/buildkit, you might see the filename instead.

This is the same thing you see when using `docker image history`.